# React component shows empty data on first load, but renders properly after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just taking some data from accounts, chunking it into separate pages then displaying the first page by default. It begins empty, but after I refresh it works properly.

```
const Dashboard = ({ accounts }) => {
const [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);

const pages = useMemo(() => {
    const pages = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i += 8) {
        pages.push(accounts.slice(i, i + 8));
    }

    return pages;
}, [accounts]);

const numOfPages = pages.length;

useEffect(() => {
    getAccount();
}, []);

const onClick = (num) => {
    if (num == -1 && pageNum == 0) {
        //Do nothing
    } else if (num == 1 && pageNum >= numOfPages - 1) {
        //Do nothing
    } else {
        setPageNum(pageNum + num);
    }
};
```

...

```
                                    <Fragment>
                                        {pages[pageNum] !== null &&
                                            pages[pageNum] !== undefined &&
                                            pages[pageNum].map((account, index) => (
                                                <SavedPassword
                                                    key={index}
                                                    site={account.site}
                                                    login={account.login}
                                                    password={account.password}
                                                />
                                            ))}
                                    </Fragment>
```

The useEffect hook with get accounts isn't actually required, I added that in hopes it would make it refresh or something. The webpage actually loads the getAccount action upon entering, regardless of what page is loaded. I've tried putting all that information into the getEffect hook, but that was actually a total nightmare. Any ideas of why it's doing this?

Comment: What does `getAccount` do? Where does the `accounts` prop come from?

Comment: getAccount calls to the backend and gets the list of accounts, which is then injected as a prop from redux. That's where the accounts prop comes from.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is in the Redux setup then. If the accounts show up after a refresh, that means you're using some sort of persistence? redux-persist? Can you also paste how the props are being passed in?

Comment: @AndreThompson Did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue.